# Using transaction scope in C# returns "A root ambient transaction was completed before the nested transaction."

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, transactionscope

I am using the transaction scope from `System.Transactions`.

I have this method where I have two insertions in database. The first Localization is inserted, but then rolled back since it fails on the second insertion.
Now the error is not with the data I send. The data is good. When I remove the transaction scope it works.
I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A root ambient transaction was completed before the nested transaction. The nested transactions should be completed first.

It also enters the second catch and disposes the scope. What could be the problem?

This is my code:

```cs
public async Task InsertCategory(InsertCategoryRequest request)
{
    using var scope = new TransactionScope();
    int localizationId;
    try
    {
        localizationId = await _localizationRepository.InsertLocalization(new Localization
        {
            English = request.NameEN,
            Albanian = request.NameAL,
            Macedonian = request.NameMK
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        scope.Dispose();
        Log.Error("Unable to insert localization {@Exception}", e);
        throw ExceptionHandler.ThrowException(ErrorCode.Localization_UnableToInsert);
    }
    
    try
    {
        await _categoryRepository.InsertCategory(new Category
        {
            Name = request.NameEN,
            LocalizationId = localizationId
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        scope.Dispose();
        Log.Error("Unable to insert category {@Exception}", e);
        throw ExceptionHandler.ThrowException(ErrorCode.Category_UnableToInsert);
    }

    scope.Complete();
    scope.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You don't need any of `scope.Dispose()`.

Comment: Why is that? @GSerg

Comment: Because you have `using var scope = new TransactionScope();` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I looked for such a long time, but after I posted I found the answer lol.
Just added `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` when constructing the Transaction Scope.

Comment: Most likely you also want to specify the isolation level as read committed. It's serializable by default, which is an overkill.